# Looking to Replace Fiber Converter, Unsure of Compatibility

Tags: home-networking, fiber

I have a TrendNet TFC-110S15 fiber converter.  It is a SC type single-mode fiber converter for a 15km run.  I was thinking of replacing it with a TrendNet TFC-1000S20 converter (20 km run), but am not sure about compatibility.  Both are single mode fiber converters running at 1310nm wavelength.  Is this a drop in replacement?  If not, what should I be looking in a new fiber converter to have a drop in replacement?

The end goal is to replace the 10/100 Ethernet jack on the old converter with a gigabit Ethernet jack.  I'm considering this as a possible solution to [this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/446245/internet-connection-running-at-half-speed-with-gigabit-switch).

Answer (score 0):

They both use the same fiber types and fiber connector types, but one does 100BASE-FX and the other does 1000BASE-LX. You can't just replace the device at one end of the fiber connection and hope the transceiver at the other end knows 1000BASE-LX as well. However, if you're in a position to switch out the gear at both ends of the fiber link, you could replace both ends with the new TrendNet TFC-1000S20, and it should work with the existing fiber.